# Selenium Java Cannot enter text in a textbox

Tags: selenium

The page has a row of cells for data entry. The cell I am having trouble with looks like:

```
<td class="sample-tree-cell omnidx-669 x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1063  editable-cell sample-measurement required odd-row x-form-invalid-field" id="ext-gen1335" data-errorqtip="<ul><li class=&quot;last&quot;>This field is required</li></ul>">
    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;" id="ext-gen1347">&nbsp;</div>
</td>
```

So when the box is clicked and '1234' is manually entered, a new span is created so the cell html looks like:

```
<td class="sample-tree-cell omnidx-669 x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1063 x-grid-dirty-cell editable-cell sample-measurement required odd-row x-grid-cell-selected" id="ext-gen1335" data-errorqtip="<ul><li class=&quot;last&quot;>This field is required</li></ul>">
    <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;" id="ext-gen1347">
    <span class="qtip-value " data-qtip="1234">1234</span></div></td>
```

This is everything I have tried:

```
        String txt_omniDxBox = "//table/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]/div";
        obj = driver.findElement(By.xpath(txt_omniDxBox));
        obj.click();
        sleep(1000);

        obj.sendKeys("1234");
        //String scriptSetAttrValue = "arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1],arguments[2])";
        //js.executeScript(scriptSetAttrValue, obj, "innerText", "1234");
        //js.executeScript(driver.findElement(By.xpath(txt_omniDxBox)).setAttribute("data-qtip", "1234");
        //js.executeScript("document.getElementById('ext-gen1347').setAttribute("innerText", "1234")");
```

The cursor is set in the textbox but I get the error: element not interactable.
Click works, so is there a way to just send text to the page?

Comment: you'll have to target the <input> element that is created after you click on the cell. (after cursor is in cell, right-click and choose inspect to see the input tag)  You should probably use webdriverwaits with expected conditions for this, too.  (instead of using sleep)

Comment: Unfortunately the input tag is not created till after you click out of the cell.

Comment: if the cursor is blinking in there, it's an input.